# How to Hide lines after isPrintRepeatedValues="false" in Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have requirement to hide the line after setting a property isPrintRepeatedValues="false" and values is not repeated but the getting line.and check the below image and highlighted with red color arrow.

[image]

That is shouldn't come and USA will come central. Can i achive this requirement if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use subreport for all fields exclude first field. 
First field and subreport placed into frame with borders.
For first field set properties:

```
stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight"
verticalAlignment="Middle"
```

First field haven't borders.

Comment: little discussion here http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/540266/merging-rows-table

Comment: Thank SanBez.I achvied group by and use printwhenexpression.Its hidden the line in PDF.But not in html/excelsheet

Comment: When you use subreport printwhenexpression is not need. Comment is unclear.